# Firefox and Chrome gives "too many redirects" error on the following Facebook Connect implementation

Tags: facebook, laravel, facebook-php-sdk

```
// GET "giris-yap/facebook"
public function action_facebook_index()
{
    $facebook = IoC::resolve('facebook-sdk');
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if($user)
    {
        $profile = $facebook->api('/me');

        return View::make('home.login-facebook')
            ->with('message_area', null)
            ->with('username', $profile['username']);
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to($facebook->getLoginUrl(array('next' => 'http://dugun.dev/giris-yap/facebook')));
    }
}

// POST "giris-yap/facebook"
public function action_facebook_process()
{
    $facebook = IoC::resolve('facebook-sdk');
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $profile = $facebook->api('/me');

    $input = Input::all();

    Auth::attempt(array('username' =>  $profile['username'], 'password' => $input['password']));

    if(Auth::check())
        return Redirect::to('account');
    else
        return View::make('home.login-facebook')
            ->with('message_area', 'Giriş denemesi başarısız.')
            ->with('username', $profile['username']);
}
```

The code above works flawlessly on my machine but my friend get's an error on both Chrome and Firefox.

Chrome: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Firefox: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

It happens on this line:

```
return Redirect::to($facebook->getLoginUrl(array('next' => 'http://dugun.dev/giris-yap/facebook')));
```

In theory; I redirect to Facebook, then Facebook redirects back to `action_facebook_index()`, and it repeats. However, Facebook should not be redirecting it. It should show user the form to give application permissions, then redirect back. That works normally on my personal computer, but my friend is having the issues above.

Is there anything I can do to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Facebook Application being in Sanbox mode, so only as the application owner, I had access to the required API's. If someone else made the request, Facebook redirected them back and hence creating an infinite loop.

The issue was solved by closing Sandbox mode on Facebook Application Settings and giving appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably won't fix it but you should separate some of the logic. The part that checks for a logged in Facebook user should be in a Route filter. Then remove the array passed as parameter to the getLoginUrl method (Facebook automatically redirects to the requesting page).

Also your friend might have cookies turned off?